# intermediate Field extension by irreducible polynomial

Tags: field-theory

Thanks for any help or comments.

Suppose $f(x)\in F[x]$ is an irreducible polynomial of composite degree $n$. So there exist an closure field $\bar{F}$ such that $f(x)$ is completely reducible in $\bar{F}$ and $[\bar{F}:F]=n$. Is it true that for every prime integer $p$ where $p|n$ there exist a field extension $K$ of $F$, such that $F\subset K\subset \bar{F}$, $[K:F]=p$ and $f(x)$ is reducible in $K[x]$?

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not true in general. By Galois theory (assuming $f$ is separable), if we write $G$ for the Galois group of $\bar{F}/F$, what you are asking amounts to "for any $p|n$, is there a subgroup $H$ of $G$ of index $p$ ?".

But take a field extension with Galois group the alternating group $A_5$ (this exists). Then $2$ divides the order of the group (which is $60$), but there is no subgroup of index $2$ because a subgroup of index $2$ is always normal, and $A_5$ is simple.

Comment: Thanks.  If in addition such an intermediate field exist, is it true that $p(x)$ is reducible?

Comment: Wait, I didn't notice there was a mistake in your question, I'll edit to take it into account, and I'll answer your second question too.

Comment: Ah, unless "composite degree" means "degree of the splitting field" ?

Comment: Yes. it is degree of splitting field.

Comment: Ah ok, never saw that terminology before. Well, then no. For instance, take $f= X^3 -2$ on $F=\mathbb{Q}$. Then $f$ is still irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}(j)$.

Comment: Is there a counterexample for finite field $F$?

Comment: No, if $F$ is finite then you can always find an intermediary extension of any degree dividing $n$, and in this extension $f$ is reducible (and furthermore the extension is unique).